# Temporarily Showing the Navigation and Status bars in Immersive Mode

Tags: android, android-immersive

In Android when in Immersive Mode, swiping in from the bottom or other edges (based on current orientation) reveals the status bar and navigation bar (which auto-hides later). I want to trigger this programmatically by touching the fingerprint scanner. How can I achieve this? There are some commands in the Android shell to emulate a swipe action programmatically, but is this that the only way to do this?